# Showing that $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+1, Y^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, ring-isomorphism

A problem in my textbook asks me to show that $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+1, Y^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$. After I've tried solving this for a long time, I looked at the textbook's hint and it said that I should consider the homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{R}[X, Y] \to \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$, $\phi(f)=(f(i,i), f(i, -i))$ and this would be a surjective ring homomorphism whose kernel is the ideal $(X^2+1, Y^2+1)$, so I would be done.

The fact that this is a ring homomorphism is pretty obvious to me. However, I am really struggling to show that this function is surjective and to find the kernel.

I think that this all stems from the fact that I am not used to the arithmetic properties of polynomial rings in two indeterminates. Anyway, back to the problem. For the surjectivity I tried playing arround with a few polynomials and I hoped to kind of guess the right one, but no succes. Showing that $(X^2+1, Y^2+1)\subset \operatorname{Ker}\phi$ is really straightforward, but the other inclusion is really killing me. So, how should I go about doing this?

Comment: I would write $f(X,Y)=(Y^2+1)g(X,Y)+a(X)Y+b(X)$. Since $f(i,i)=f(i,-i)=0$ we get $a(i)i+b(i)=0$ and $-a(i)i+b(i)=0$. Then $a(i)=b(i)=0$ and since $a,b\in\mathbb R[X]$ it follows that $X^2+1$ divides $a(X)$ and $b(X)$.

Comment: @user26857 thank you very much! Yes, after I thought about this for a little longer this is how I also wrote down the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel: Doing polynomial division where you have two polynomials in multiple indeterminates is in general a tricky business where you first have to fix an ordering. In this case, we can kind of hack our way through.

Let $f(X,Y)$ be the polynomial we want to divide by $X^2+1$ and $Y^2+1$.
We can write $f(X,Y)=(X^2+1)(...)+(Y^2+1)(...)+(c_1XY+c_2X+c_3Y+c_4)$.

When we divide by $X^2+1$, we are effectively saying replace $X^2$ with $-1$ and likewise with $Y^2$ and $-1$. So you can get a "remainder" where all the $X$ terms have degree $1$ and $Y$ terms have degree $1$.

Now, evaluate at $(i,i)$ and $(i,-i)$ to see

$0=f(i,i)=0(...)+0(...)+c_1(-1)+c_2i+c_3i+c_4=(-c_1+c_4)+i(c_2+c_3)$

$0=f(i,-i)=0(...)+0(...)+c_1(1)+c_2i-c_3i+c_4=(c_1+c_4)+i(c_2-c_3)$

You can solve the simultaneous equations in $c_i$ to see that all $c_i$ have to be $0$.

Surjective: Let $(a+bi,c+di)\in\mathbb{C}^2$.

We look at the "remainder" term from before $f(X,Y)=c_1XY+c_2X+c_3Y+c_4$. We want $f(i,i)=a+bi, f(i,-i)=c+di$.

You get $a+bi=(-c_1+c_4)+(c_2+c_3)i$ and $c+di=(c_1+c_4)+i(c_2-c_3)$. You can again repeat the same thing as before and solve for the simultaneous equations.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Everything is clear, except this: $f(X,Y)=(X^2+1)(...)+(Y^2+1)(...)+(c_1XY+c_2X+c_3Y+c_4)$. Why can we write this? So far, whenever I needed to divide a polynomial in say $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]$ by something I would look at it as an element of $(\mathbb{R}[X])([Y])$ and use the "standard" polynomial division theorem. However, I can't see how I could obtain the expression you wrote

Comment: If you have a term $X^{2n+n_i} Y^{2m+m_i}=(X^{2n+n_i}-1+1)(Y^{2m+m_i}-1+1)$ (with $n_i,m_i\in \{0,1\}$) and you "divide" by $X^2+1$ and $Y^2+1$, we get $(-1)^{n+m}X^{n_i}Y^{m_i}$.

Comment: I think I see what you're doing: you are writing $\displaystyle f=\sum_{k, j}a_{kj}X^kY^j$ and you are dividing each monomial $X^kY^j$ by $X^2+1$ and $Y^2+1$ consecutively, right?

Comment: That's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "So, how should I go about doing this?"

**Answer:**

$$\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+1, Y^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}\{1, \overline{x}\} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$$

If $F_1:=x+y, F_2:=x-y$ it follows

$$\phi(F_1)=(i,0), \phi(F_2)=(0,i), \phi(F_1^2)=(-1,0), \phi(F_2^2)=(0,-1)$$

hence

$$\phi(bF_1-aF_1^2)=(a+ib,0), \phi(-aF_2^2+bF_2)=(0,a+ib)$$

hence the map is surjective. The quotient

$$A:=\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+1, Y^2+1)$$

has a basis given as follows

$$A:=\mathbb{R}\{1,\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{xy}\}$$

and you must use this basis to give an explicit isomorphism

$$\phi: A \cong \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}.$$

You find

$$\phi(1)=(1,1),\phi(x)=(i,i), \phi(y)=(i,-i), \phi(xy)=(-1,1).$$

You must check that the following vectors in $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ are linearly independent:

$$(1,1),(i,i),(i,-i),(-1,1).$$

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I would be interested in seeing how I can do the problem by using the hint from the textbook (this is because I don't know anything about the tensor product and I am not supposed to solve it like this)